# Custom user creation and auto login problem

Tags: user-registration, authentication

I am trying to create a custom user and then log them in programatically, whereafter I want to redirect them to a payment page.

I have the following code in my theme's functions.php file:

```
function sp_registration_process_hook() {

    if (isset($_POST['adduser']) && isset($_POST['add-nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['add-nonce'], 'add-user')) {
        // die if the nonce fails
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['add-nonce'],'add-user') ) {
            wp_die('Sorry! That was secure, guess you\'re cheatin huh!');
        } else {

            //create a new role
            remove_role( 'service_provider' );
            $result = add_role(
                'service_provider',
                __( 'Service Provider' ),
                array(
                    'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
                    'edit_posts'   => true,
                    'delete_posts' => true, // Use false to explicitly deny
                    'level_0'      => true,
                    'level_1'      => true
                )
            );

            // auto generate a password
            $user_pass = wp_generate_password();

            echo $user_pass;

            $user_login = esc_attr( $_POST['user_name'] );
            $user_email = esc_attr( $_POST['email'] );

            // setup some error checks
            if ( !$user_login ) {
                $error = 'A username is required for registration.';
            }
            elseif ( username_exists($user_login) ) {
                $error = 'Sorry, that username already exists!';
            }
            elseif ( !is_email($user_email, true) ) {
                $error = 'You must enter a valid email address.';
            }
            elseif ( email_exists($user_email) ) {
                $error = 'Sorry, that email address is already used!';
            }
            // setup new users and send notification
            else
            {
                $user_id = wp_create_user($user_email, $user_pass, $user_email);
                wp_update_user(
                    array(
                        'ID' => $user_id,
                        'nickname' => $user_email
                    )
                );
                $user = new WP_User($user_id);
                $user->set_role('service_provider');

                custom_login( $user_email, $user_pass );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('process_sp_registration_form', 'sp_registration_process_hook');

function custom_login($email, $pass) {
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $email;
    $creds['user_password'] = $pass;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();
}
// run it before the headers and cookies are sent
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

The user gets created fine, but it does not log in the user automatically.  When I look at the front end, the user is definitely not logged in after the post.

Can you see anything obvious that I am doing wrong?  Any help will be appreciated.

Jacques

Answer (score 0):

I have similar functionality on one of my app. I used [`wp_set_auth_cookie()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie).

Remove the `custom_login()` function and use `wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id)` in its place.

Comment: Hi Sisir, tried that, makes no difference - user is created but not logged in.

Comment: Can you try hooking into `template_redirect` instead of `process_sp_registration_form`? The code must be run before any output to browser.